# Print a file from Watir

Tags: autoit, watir-webdriver, rautomation

I'm looking at [Watir-Webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/) to manipulate a browser.  In particular, I'd like to open a local file and print it to a PDF file.

Yes, wkhtmltopdf would be a good thing, but it's not working for me on debian squeeze, for reasons that are difficult to ascertain.  The page contains Javascript, which rules out many html-to-pdf options.  wkhtmltopdf works on OS X, same version (0.9.9), so I know it's not a problem with how I'm using it (PDFKit and Ruby).  I'd just like to sidestep these issues and try a different way. Opening up chromium on debian shows a perfectly rendered page.

How does one "print" from Watir?

**Edit**: After [more reading](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/classes/Watir/Browser.html), I think there is no way to do this.

Comment: The 'more reading' link above is for a pretty old version of watir, not even watir-webdriver.  A more current version of the rdoc would be here:  http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-webdriver/master/frames.  Although it doesn't really change the answer that there is no direct way to do this with watir (unless the screenshot trick works or there is a webdriver function for this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a png sreenshot, then use the prawn gem to convert the png screenshot to a pdf:

```
require 'prawn'
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.start 'watirwebdriver.com'
b.driver.save_screenshot 'screenshot.png'
Prawn::Document.generate 'screenshot.pdf' do
  image 'screenshot.png', :scale => 0.5
end
b.close
```

Comment: Not sure if I'll use this solution, but it works, you crazy genius.  +1

Comment: Note: the screenshot is Selenium (b.driver).  It doesn't actually require Watir.

Comment: not sure what you mean. Yes, you can do this via selenium-webdriver, but watir-webdriver is simply an API over selenium-webdriver, hence the name

Comment: I was just noting for myself that Watir is not required.  In this case, the Selenium code looks almost the same.  Fewer dependencies is often better.  However, I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use something that lets you do automation at the OS level.  such as Autoit or maybe RAutomation.   not sure what exists to do this on *nix operating systems.

Watir only drives the browser in terms of what is inside the browser window, it has very limited capability to work the menus of the browser itself.